# Why cannot access json?

Tags: jquery, json

```
 function loadResponse(filter) {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'path/to/example.json',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         beforeSend: function () {
             console.log('loading');
         },
         success: function (response) {
             //console.log('success, filtering response..');

             var filtered = $(response).filter(function (i, n) {
                 return n.type === filter; //not working
             });
             console.log('filter by json ' + filtered);

             for (var key in filtered) {
                 if (filtered.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     console.log('list ' + filtered[key]["description"]);
                     console.log('list ' + filtered[key]["name"]);

                 }
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

The `console.log` kept giving `undefined` for the description or name. But however I tested without:

```
var filtered = $(response).filter(function (i,n) {
    return n.type === filter; //not working
});
```

Able to get description and name in `console.log`. Seems like `$(response).filter` does not return somthing. not sure where it went wrong.

**Update**

See JSON -- response is supposed to print out name and type. so need to filter type inside json

```
[
    {
      "name": "Jonathan Suh",
      "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "William Philbin",
      "type": "judge, hobbyist"
    },
    {
      "name": "Allison McKinnery",
      "type": "hobbyist"
    }
  ];



   $('.filter a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        loadResponse($(this).attr('id'));
      });
```

Example:

```
<a href='#' id="hobbyist">Hobbyist</a>
```

So click on this above, it should give me list of 3 people who are hobbyists.

Comment: What is `filter` meant to be in there?

Comment: you will have to show us what is the `response` from the ajax. (*and also what the `filter` variable holds*)

Comment: @arkascha - need to filter by type that matches with the click on id attribute so could get details from specific people on list by certain type

Comment: Provided response is an actual JSON object, just do `response.filter()` else use `JSON.parse(response).filter()`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - I did try JSON.parse(response) but it gives me error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: That was not an answer to my question. That explains the `filter()` function. I was asking about the `filter` variable in there. The thing right before the "// not working"... Since you compare against it and state "that does not work" it would be interestig to know what the variable actually contains...

Comment: @arkascha  - by that i mean it doesn't do anything. It doesnt even get any data inside that function. see the code above that i have updated

Comment: LOL, did you even bother to _read_ what I wrote? Apparently not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) filter will:

> Reduce the set of matched **elements** to those that match the **selector** or pass the function's test.

(emphasis mine)

I think it works on DOM elements not JSON objects

You can try using [`jquery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

**UPDATED**

Sample using `grep()` -> See console for outputs when clicking

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [{
    "name": "Jonathan Suh",
    "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
  }, {
    "name": "William Philbin",
    "type": "judge, hobbyist"
  }, {
    "name": "Allison McKinnery",
    "type": "hobbyist"
  }];

  var doFilter = function(arr, filterParam) {
    return jQuery.grep(arr, function(n, i) {
      console.log(n.type.indexOf(filterParam));
      return (n.type.indexOf(filterParam) > -1);
    });
  };


  $(".filter").on('click', function() {
    var filterName = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(filterName);
    if (filterName) {
      var filteredResults = doFilter(arr, filterName);

      console.log(filteredResults);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>See console for outputs when clicking</h3>
<a href='#' class="filter" id="hobbyist">Hobbyist</a>
<br/>
<a href='#' class="filter" id="judge">Judge</a>
```

Comment: i tried it as you suggested, but it doesnt return anything either. more like it is not doing anything

Comment: How are you using it? I added a sample implementation... Hopefully it will help you

Comment: thanks a lot for example. One qn is arr, if it is external link to json file, how to access to arr inside the click event?

Comment: I'm sure this is working fine, but so is filter() - http://jsfiddle.net/vo1t6znn/